# TargetStatus DNE in ObserverBehaviour

Tags: vuforia

**Documentation:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTEqO.png)

**Error:**

```
error CS0426: The type name 'TargetStatus' does not exist in the type 'ObserverBehaviour'
```

**Calling in Method:**

```
void OnImageTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour.TargetStatus previousStatus)
    { ... }
```

- Does anyone know what's wrong with the above code? I am unable to use the `TargetStatus` property of `ObserverBehaviour`.